# PHP: Finding the correct algorithm for date(); with time difference in a year

Tags: php, algorithm, date

I am currently working on an algorithm to autoplay a unique audio-message for each day of a year, which is spoken by one of seven different persons depending on the day of the week.

For example: On **May 7th** the audio file **05-07.mp3** will be autoplayed and a Barack Obama image with the name **04.png** is shown, because it is Thursday. The day after tomorrow is May 8th so 05-08.mp3 gets played, with Angela Merkel as 05.png.

Now here's the problem:

The beginning of this year was a Thursday, next year January 1st is a Friday. So if I use my script as I explained, Angela Merkel with image 05.png would use the voice of Barack Obama with 01-01.mp3 ..

How can I fix my script, so that I can create my audio files with dates in it's filename? What do I have to change? Another problem is that next year is also a February 29th!

Currently my script uses this php code:

```
<audio><source src="/mp3/<?php echo date("j"); echo "-" . date("m"); ?>.mp3" /></audio>

<img src="/png/<?php echo date("N"); ?>.png">
```

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're asking.  Do you have an mp3 file for every possible person and date?  I don't see where you need an algorithm.

Comment: Do you have an audio file for each day of the year but an image for each day of the week? It's a little hard to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Im also confused. What exactly do you need you script to do? It is not the expected behavior to play 01-01.mp3 and show 05.png on the next January 1st? Note: you may want to use date('d') instead of date('j')

Comment: I have 365 different MP3s, which are alternately quotes of 7 different presidents. Each MP3 gets played on one day a year, and the correct president should get displayed.

Comment: Well if you only have 365 mp3s, how do you expect this to work?  Do you plan on shifting the president's number the next year?  And like you said, you'll have to shift it again when it comes to leap year.  So I don't think storing the president's pictures by number is the ideal solution.

Comment: This is the problem. The easiest method from my opinion would be to duplicate the image of each president so that they are in total 365 images, with file names in date format as well, e.g. Obama would be 01-01.png, 01-08.png, 01-15.png etc. (all identical). But then a lot of memory would get used ...

Comment: Does it matter if they are in order or are you just trying to match the mp3 of the date to the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a database to store the mp3 and the respective names. If you can't use a database, alternatively you can rename the sound's filename to something like obama_01-01.mp3 and then you can check.

@edit

```
$soundname = 'obama_01-01.mp3';
$imagename = explode('_',$soundname)[0];

$imagename .= '.png'
```

Then you rename your images' names to obama.png and so on

@edit2

to print the sound you can use

```
glob("*_01-01.mp3");
```

[PHP: glob - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

[PHP: explode - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: The last recommendation will not work. How should I find out if the mp3 has Obama in its name? But using a database for the pngs would be an idea... I hoped to fix this without SQL since I have no knowledge at all :(

Comment: You could match this with `glob("*_01-01.mp3");` which should return "obama_01-01.mp3"

Comment: @OtakuKyon above comment also useful to you ^

Comment: Ok wait, this seemed to be a good approach. But how should I print "obama_01-01.mp3"? PHP does not know when it has to echo "obama" before the date ..

Comment: Ok thanks guys! I will check it, but I am almost sure, it will work :)